# how to get a value which points to a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have a value like that

```
var myvalue = myfunction(1,2);
```

what I need is that
GETTING `myfunction(a,b)` as a string..

I mean not "myfunction's value"

hmmm, let me explain,

`myfunction(1,2)` returns `1+2=3`

if I type

```
alert(myvalue)
```

it returns `3`
but I need `myfunction(a,b)` AS IT'S TYPED when I use alert. NOT IT'S VALUE

think it like

```
var myvalue='myfunction(a,b)'
```

now, if i use Alert, it gives me myfunction(a,b)

how can I do that?

Comment: what are you going to do with the value? why doesn't `var myvalue="myfunction(a,b)"` work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var myvalue = function()
{
  myfunction(1,2);
};
```

myvalue is a anonymous function that calls myfunction with the specified parameters.  You can call it, and if you print it for debugging, it will look something like:

```
function () { 
   myfunction(1, 2); 
}
```

Comment: Matthew, thank you.
it works but my value isn't like that.

var myvalue = function()
{
  myfunction(1,2);
};

I can get this on console.log as its typed
--------
is it possible to get myvalue if it looks like the following?

my value=function(a,b)

Comment: If you have the code `myvalue = myfunction(a,b);`, myvalue will always be the return value from myfunction.  There's no getting around that.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the string value of a function, you can use the builtin `toString` method

```
var f1 = function(a, b) {
    return a + b;
};

function f2(a, b) {
    return a + b;
};

console.log(f1.toString());
console.log(f2.toString());
```

yields

```
function (a, b) {
    return a + b;
}
function f2(a, b) {
    return a + b;
}
```

But why do you want to do this?